# How to describe snapshots by OwnerIds and Filters using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, snapshot

How to describe snapshots owned by me and filtering by tag simultaneously?

It describe snapshots owned by me with code below:

```
import boto3
region_src = 'us-east-1'
client_src = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region_src)

def get_snapshots_src():
    response = client_src.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['012345678900'])
    return response["Snapshots"]

snap = get_snapshots_src()
print(*snap, sep="\n")
```

But when I add "Filters", its starts ignoring "OwnerIds" and filtering only by tag.

```
client_src.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['012345678900'],Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Disaster_Recovery', 'Values': ['Full']}])
```

I'm follow an official boto3 documentation:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Filters and OwnerIds options are working separately. I expect that the OwnerIds option is an abbreviation of the Filters option for owner-id, because I also got the result that the OwnerIds option is ignored.

And so, you can use the filter option such as

```
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'tag:key',
            'Values': [
                'value'
            ]
        },
        {
            'Name': 'owner-id',
            'Values': [
                'value'
            ]
        }
    ]
```

and it will work well same as me.

---

```
Filters (list) --
The filters.

description - A description of the snapshot.
encrypted - Indicates whether the snapshot is encrypted (true | false )
owner-alias - Value from an Amazon-maintained list (amazon | self | all | aws-marketplace | microsoft ) of snapshot owners. Not to be confused with the user-configured AWS account alias, which is set from the IAM console.
owner-id - The ID of the AWS account that owns the snapshot.
progress - The progress of the snapshot, as a percentage (for example, 80%).
snapshot-id - The snapshot ID.
start-time - The time stamp when the snapshot was initiated.
status - The status of the snapshot (pending | completed | error ).
tag :<key> - The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. Use the tag key in the filter name and the tag value as the filter value. For example, to find all resources that have a tag with the key Owner and the value TeamA , specify tag:Owner for the filter name and TeamA for the filter value.
tag-key - The key of a tag assigned to the resource. Use this filter to find all resources assigned a tag with a specific key, regardless of the tag value.
volume-id - The ID of the volume the snapshot is for.
volume-size - The size of the volume, in GiB.
(dict) --
A filter name and value pair that is used to return a more specific list of results from a describe operation. Filters can be used to match a set of resources by specific criteria, such as tags, attributes, or IDs. The filters supported by a describe operation are documented with the describe operation.
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I didn't get how it finds 'owner-id' with a dash(-), In the description, it OwnerId.

Comment: @OrestGulman If you see the description for Filter section carefully, you will notice that the red characters and there is the `owner-id`.