# Convert shell script to Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

> aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID --query
> "Snapshots[?(StartTime<='$dtt')].[SnapshotId]" --output text | tr '\t'
> '\n' | sort

I have this shell script which I want to convert to python.
I tried looking at the boto3 documentation and came up with this

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds = [os.environ['AWS_ACCOUNT_ID']], )
```

But I can't figure out how to change that --query tag in python.
I couldn't find it in the documentation.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to describe snapshots by OwnerIds and Filters using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785362/how-to-describe-snapshots-by-ownerids-and-filters-using-boto3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore the `--query` portion and everything after it, and process that within Python instead.

First, store the result of the call in a variable:

```py
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds = ['self'])
```

It will return something like:

```json
{
    'NextToken': '',
    'Snapshots': [
        {
            'Description': 'This is my snapshot.',
            'OwnerId': '012345678910',
            'Progress': '100%',
            'SnapshotId': 'snap-1234567890abcdef0',
            'StartTime': datetime(2014, 2, 28, 21, 28, 32, 4, 59, 0),
            'State': 'completed',
            'VolumeId': 'vol-049df61146c4d7901',
            'VolumeSize': 8,
        },
    ],
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

Therefore, you can use `response['Snapshots']` to extract your desired results, for example:

```py
for snapshot in response['Snapshots']:
  if snapshot['StartTime'] < datetime(2022, 6, 1):
    print(snapshot['SnapshotId'])
```

It's really all Python at that point.